# how does github 52 week participation work?

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm confused about my github 52 week participation graphs. Most of the projects that I have on there only have one author (me). However the "commits by owner" on the 52 week participation are zero, even though all my commits are by me.

My Page: https://github.com/yule

Comment: I'm guessing this not a stack overflow question by the downvotes. Not sure where to find this out though...

Comment: Since StackOverflow includes coverage of programmer tools, it could certainly be argued that Github is a programmer tool.  I don't know why people are so quick to downvote questions around here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably that the email addresses in the Author fields of the commits in those projects don't match any of the email addresses associated with your GitHub account.  If you go to "Account Settings" there's an option called "Email Addresses" where you can add additional email addresses that are associated with you, so GitHub can identify those commits as yours.

Comment: No problem. I should say that I've no idea how frequently those graphs are regenerated - it might take a while for that to have effect.

Comment: Is there any reason the graph wouldn't work at all even when the emails addresses are added to a github account?

Comment: @Chris: that would probably best as a new question, so that you can include more detail about what you're seeing (e.g. exactly what "the graph [doesn't] work" means)

Comment: As a side - my graphs updated the day after I did a commit after adding emails

Comment: My graphs are completely empty. Don't show any bars even though I have a bunch of commits spanning the past 5+ months. The emails are all added except for a couple. I thought maybe the initial commit didn't have a correct email but it does.

Comment: @Chris: it sounds as if you should report that to GitHub