# Git More than one value for the key user.name/email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, configuration, github

**Problem 1.**
 when I run the command

```
$ git config --global user.name
# or
$ git config --global user.email
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: More than one value for the key user.name/email
```

So it seems like I have multiple values stored against both my user name and email. I want to have one value stored in each.

**Problem 2**. 
The name shown against my commits on github is not linked to my account. means not hyper linked its blocked.

I searched a lot but got no satisfactory result to my problems. anyone can please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows or a Unix based system? If you are on a Unix based system you can check the config inside the config file. Go to your home folder and in there, there should be a hidden file called .gitconfig open it and see what info you have there. Maybe there is an error on the file.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to Problem 1: 
First look to see what is listed in the config:

`git config --list`

Example output:

```
enter code here

user.email=abarker@cern.ch
user.name=fiveisgreen
user.github=fiveisgreen
user.name=Anthony
```

In this example, user.name is listed twice. To remove the duplicate do:

```
git config --global --unset user.name Anthony
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in ~/.gitconfig

I'm guessing yours should look something like this:

```
...
[user]
  name = Sami
  email = xxx@xx.com
  name = Sami
  email = xxx@xxx.com
....
```

Just remove the dupliucate entries to get rid of the message.

In terms of linking to github, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7123772/671422)

Comment: when i run the command 
git config --get-all user.name
i see something like 
Sami Ulhaq
Sami ul haq
Same is the case with user.email
xxx@gmail.com
[branch

Comment: Thanks the dual name and email issue resolved ... i also removed the alternative email now lets see whats happening ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
git config -l #shows you what name, email and other stuff is saved
cat ~/.gitconfig #shows you samething(what's saved in your /home/username/.gitconfig)
```

To change stuff on existing commits in your machine you can try this on the commandline:

```
$ git config user.name "Your Name"
$ git config user.email "your@address.com"
$ git submodule foreach --recursive 'git config user.name "Your Name" && git config    user.email "your@address.com"'
```

.... see rest here : https://gist.github.com/carlosmcevilly/2221249

ps:if you have already commited stuff and want snyc with github, then ask another question(that is separate issue)